# Elastic search - caching results for queries with size and from parameters

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

I am trying to optimise performance of my queries. My queries have sort and aggregations. Additionally, I specify from and size parameters as I need data to be fetched in batches.

I am using request cache which makes sure aggregations are not executed every time. However, I have not been able to find a way to cache the query data.

Looked at:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-request-cache.html

> "By default, the requests cache will only cache the results of search
>   requests where size=0, so it will not cache hits, but it will cache
>   hits.total, aggregations, and suggestions."

Is there a way I can cache search results in such cases?

Sample query:

```
GET myIndex/_search?request_cache=true
{
    "size": 20,
    "from": 0,
    "query": { ... },
    "sort": { ... },
    "aggregations": { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this assumption holds still true. A workaround might be to send two queries, one search query and one aggregation query, so that the aggregation part can be cached.

Have you found out what actually is the slow part? The search or the aggs?

Comment: Search is slow. Aggs are very fast. My query has a sort and also has fetch for inner_hits.

Comment: you can use the profile API or install kibana x-pack and have a UI for this API to see which parts of your query a slow. That might help to decide if you need to change your index structure to optimize. Maybe having more memory to have more filesystem cache to cache the doc values for sorting might help, hard to tell from the distance.

Comment: Thanks. I used the profile api and the breakdown shows that create_weight and build_scorer took majority of the time for my queries.